# Android - maven - build error

Tags: android, maven, maven-plugin

maven-plugin , the build is success , but the when i try mvn clean install i got this logs

```
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
```

[INFO] [clean:clean]
[INFO] Deleting file-set: distrib (included: [*.*], excluded: [])
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-changes-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ejb-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] Reloading plugin container for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin. The plugin artifact has changed.
[INFO] [site:attach-descriptor]
[INFO] [install:install]
[INFO] Installing D:\RSM\mobile\fd-mobile-android\pom.xml to C:\Users\hkhwileh.m2\repository\com\firstderivatives\rsm\mobile\android\fd-mobile-androi
d-parent\5.4-SNAPSHOT\fd-mobile-android-parent-5.4-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
[ERROR] Cannot create the APKBuilder object
```

com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\RSM\mobile\fd-mobile-android\application\target\classes.dex does not
exist
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:455)
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.(ApkBuilder.java:386)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkBuilder.(ApkBuilder.java:197)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkMojo.doAPKWithAPKBuilder(ApkMojo.java:206)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkMojo.createApkFile(ApkMojo.java:171)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkMojo.execute(ApkMojo.java:144)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:451)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:558)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:499)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:478)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:330)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:291)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:336)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:287)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\RSM\mobile\fd-mobile-android\application\target\classes.dex does not exist
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.checkInputFile(ApkBuilder.java:828)
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:432)
        ... 27 more

and the tail 
 so any one can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' guessing you are using **maven-android-plugin** to build your application.
The problem is that you have to pack your classes to dex file before invoking **android:apk** goal.
To convert classes to dex format you need to use android:dex goal you also need to generate some other files.

The whole command I use to build Android applications is:

`mvn clean compile android:generate-sources android:dex android:apk`

Comment: This is completely wrong. The goals you mentioned are automatically bound to the correct lifecycle phases. Just run mvn clean install and it will do it all automatically.

Comment: Also the plugin has long been renamed to android-maven-plugin and you should NOT be using the old version at this stage anymore

Answer (score 0):

Provide more details about your project and maybe file a bug. Also try it with the latest 3.0.0-alpha release..

Update: at this stage the latest release is 3.5.0 and generally if you keep your Android SDK up to date (and you should), you should also follow the release of the Android Maven Plugin.